# Shutdown error on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, redhat, centos6, centos6.5

On a KVM host, after gracefully shutting down the guest KVM, I get:

```
[root@kvm]# /sbin/shutdown -h now

Broadcast message from vmadmin@kvm.mattermedia.com
        (/dev/pts/1) at 15:23 ...

The system is going down for halt NOW!
**shutdown: Method "EmitEvent" with signature "sasb" on interface "com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6" doesn't exist**
```

And **I cannot reboot the machine**. The same happens for -Ph or -r.

Thanks

**UPDATE 1: I will place this question on hold until the next time I have to restart this machine.**

**UPDATE 2: `reboot` works.**

Comment: How about `poweroff` and `reboot` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.. did you tried `halt`? one of the first I'd do is head over to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-` to see how my interfaces are configured,  you're saying it's CentOS, yet I'm also seeing `ubuntu` there, so double check, I think your problem is somewhere there...

Comment: The Ubuntu reference is because EL6 uses [Upstart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart).

Comment: @ewwhite I'm using CentOS on one of my boxes, and I'm not seeing any ubuntu references in there, probably because I'm not using upstart, thanks for pointing this out for me.

Comment: do a find&grep for "com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6". it's in there a few times. CentOS 6.5

Comment: didn't try halt, poweroff or reboot. it's always been `shutdown` on this server.

Comment: @Gaia Please try them.